# Modelsim does not show sim window

Tags: modelsim

I'm new to `ModelSim` software and also `VHDL` codes. I want to `simulate my test bench` code via ModelSim. I used a tutorial from [this site](https://nandland.com/introduction-to-modelsim-for-beginners/). `For first time I ran it perfectly` but after that I can't see "`sim window`".

In other words after selecting test bench as below:

[image]

**I can't see "sim window"** (something like below to `add wave`):

[image]

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Clear all dialogue boxes from the ModelSim window so you can see the menu headings near the top, underneath the icons: File, Edit, View, Compile etc.

On the View menu, click on Wave to display the Wave window.